# how to expand the size of the DataType.MultilineText

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have define the following on my Model class:-

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

On the view I have the following:-

```
<span class="f"> Description :- </span> 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
```

now the output will be a small text area, but it will not show all the text . so how I can control the size of the DataType.MultilineText ?

**:::EDIT:::**

I have added the following to the CSS file:-

```
.f {
    font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
}
.f textarea {
    width: 850px;
    height: 700px;
}
```

And I have defined this :-

```
<div >
<span class="f"> Description :- </span> 
@Html.TextArea("Description")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

But nothing actually changed regarding the multi-line display.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, with DataType set to MultilineText in the model:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

And in the View specifying the HTML attribute "rows":

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { rows = "4" } })
```

Generates HTML like that:

```
<textarea ... rows="4"></textarea>
```

A text area with 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

> so how I can control the size of the DataType.MultilineText ?

You could define a class to the textarea:

```
@Html.TextArea("Description", new { @class = "mytextarea" })
```

and then in your CSS file:

```
.mytextarea {
    width: 850px;
    height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: but is there a way to benefit from the DataType.MultilineText to implement this ?

Comment: What do you want to benefit from? This is a server side tag specifying the data type of your template. Whether it should emit a normal input tag, a textarea, the format, ... In a web application you stylify your elements using Cascading Style Sheets. In a web application you have 3 aspects: 1. Server side, 2. javascript and 3. CSS. The server side part is used to emit some markup to the client. The javascript part is used to make this markup more dynamic and the last part is used to make it look pretty.

Comment: so what is the idea of using the [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 in this case? I though I can define it on the model level,, then the effect will be on all the view that is referencing this object..

Comment: The idea is to have this field rendered as `<textarea>` tag instead of `<input type="text">` in your markup. The difference is that the first tag allows you to enter multiline text.

Comment: so I should use TextareaFor instead of Html.EditorFor

Comment: No, you should not use TextAreaFor instead of Html.EditorFor. Did you even read my answer? You should CSS if you want to style your textarea rendered with Html.EditorFor and DataType.MultilineText. You could use TextAreaFor but it is better to use CSS which is what it is designed for.

Comment: Alright, I made a mistake. Your `textarea` is not inside the span, so the `.f textarea` rule is wrong. You could give your textarea a class using the following syntax: `@Html.TextArea("Description", new { @class = "mytextarea" })` and then style it like this `.mytextarea { width: 850px; height: 750px; }`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How to define css for `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` annotation only?